# Can you help me fix the code about visualizing kernel in 2D dimension

Tags: python, svm

I am trying to plot the kernel into 2D but I got a problem. Here I plot the polynomial kernel in 2D space. 
Can you guys help me with this. Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs, make_circles

#Generate the data
X, y = make_blobs(centers=4, random_state=8)  
y = y % 2

#Linear model
linear_svm_3d = LinearSVC().fit(X_3D, y)  
coef, intercept = linear_svm_3d.coef_.ravel(), linear_svm_3d.intercept_  

#Map data into 3D
to3d = lambda x : [x[0] ** 2, np.sqrt(2) * x[0] * x[1], x[1] ** 2]
X_3D = np.array(list(map(to3d, X)))

# show linear decision boundary  
figure = plt.figure()  
xx = np.linspace(X_3D[:, 0].min(), X_3D[:, 0].max(), 50)  
yy = np.linspace(X_3D[:, 1].min(), X_3D[:, 1].max(), 50)  
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)  
ZZ = (coef[0] * XX + coef[1] * YY + intercept) / -coef[2]  
ZZ = YY ** 2  
dec = linear_svm_3d.decision_function(np.c_[XX.ravel(), YY.ravel(), ZZ.ravel()])  
plt.contourf(XX, YY, dec.reshape(XX.shape), levels=[dec.min(), 0, dec.max()], cmap=mglearn.cm2, alpha=0.5)  
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=60, cmap=mglearn.cm2)  
plt.xlabel("feature1")
plt.ylabel("feature2")  
plt.show()
```

This is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-6b9361a03b65> in <module>()
     26 ZZ = YY ** 2
     27 dec = linear_svm_3d.decision_function(np.c_[XX.ravel(), YY.ravel(), ZZ.ravel()])
---> 28 plt.contourf(XX, YY, dec.reshape(XX.shape), levels=[dec.min(), 0, dec.max()], cmap=mglearn.cm2, alpha=0.5)
     29 plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=60, cmap=mglearn.cm2)
     30 plt.xlabel("feature1")

ValueError: Contour levels must be increasing
```

Comment: As you probably realize, this might happen if `dec.min() >= 0` or `dec.max() <= 0`. What do those look like? What if you try with `levels=None`?

Comment: It works but the result seem wrong.  https://dinhduy1995.imgur.com/all/?third_party=1